# ColdFusion using Oracle's "INSERT ... RETURNING ... INTO" statement

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I am building a simple chat application with ColdFusion and I am trying to get a message ID when I run my insert. Here is what I have so far

```
<cffunction name="putMessage" access="remote" returnformat="JSON">

     <cfargument name="message" />
     <cfset LOCAL.id = 0 />

     <cfquery name="insertquery" datasource="myDS"> 
          insert into 
               chat (message) 
          values 
               (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.message#">)
          RETURNING
               id
          INTO
               <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#LOCAL.id#">
     </cfquery>

     <cfreturn LOCAL.id />
        
</cffunction>
```

The error I am getting is

> Error Executing Database Query.
>
> Not all return parameters registered

I know there are workarounds with stored procedures, and running multiple queries. I would like to know how to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question so apologies in advance for the necromancy. In my opinion the best (and maybe only) way to accomplish this is by wrapping the `INSERT` statement in a stored procedure and returning the values from the `RETURNING ... INTO` clause in an output parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE chat_insert
  ( p_message IN VARCHAR2, r_id OUT NUMBER )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO chat ( message )
  VALUES ( p_message )
  RETURNING id INTO r_id;
END;
/
```

You can then invoke this stored procedure from ColdFusion as follows:

```
<cffunction name="putMessage" access="remote" returnformat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="message" />
    <cfset LOCAL.id = 0 />

    <cfstoredproc procedure="chat_insert" datasource="myDS">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" type="in" value="#ARGUMENTS.message#" />
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" type="out" variable="LOCAL.id" />
    </cfstoredproc>

    <cfreturn LOCAL.id />
</cffunction>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just curious and don't have Oracle to test. Using cfquery, can you just return the `r_id` variable with a `SELECT` at the end, like Mark was suggesting? Or does `returning` not work that way?

Comment: Oracle doesn't work that way - or, at least, the JDBC driver packaged with ColdFusion doesn't. You can't have more than one statement in a cfquery block like you can with MSSQL.

Comment: In fact if you call an Oracle stored proc from ColdFusion and you want to return a query you need to have an OUT parameter of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` and open up a cursor for the `SELECT` in the body of the procedure - again, unlike in MSSQL where you can just plunk in a `SELECT` as the last statement in the proc.

Comment: Yes, I just tried with the JDBC thin client from Oracle and that doesn't allow multiple statements in a single `cfquery` block either. I'm not sure that's a bad thing - it helps prevent SQL injection - but it would be nice if it were something one could turn on and off.

Comment: True, like with MySQL, just change a param in the DSN settings to enable/disable. Though given that cfquery doesn't do multiple statements, it's probably better to use a proc for stuff like this anyway.

Comment: If I had my druthers all INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs would be done through stored procs.

Answer (score -1):

ID is something *returned* by the query - not something you are going to send into the query - right? Something like (note - untested):

```
 <cfargument name="message" />
 <cfset LOCAL.id = 0 />

 <cfquery name="insertquery" datasource="myDS"> 

      DECLARE newID NUMBER;

      insert into 
           chat (message) 
      values 
           (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 
                                  value="#ARGUMENTS.message#">)
      RETURNING
           id
      INTO
          newID
 </cfquery>

 <cfreturn insertquery.newID />
```

Otherwise you are expecting the driver to turn an Oracle var into a CF var *before* CF has actually received results from the driver conneciton (you are also passing the *value* 0, and not the *name* of the var you wish to return when you use #local.id# in value="").

EDIT:
If this is an "autoincrement" field another approach is to use the "Result" variable. That looks like this.

```
<cfquery name="insertquery" datasource="myDS" result="r"> 
      insert into 
           chat (message) 
      values 
           (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 
                                  value="#ARGUMENTS.message#">)

 </cfquery>

<cfreturn r.rowID/>
```

RowID is the Oracle version I think. Note - this is CF8 or later.

Comment: Yes.. you will need to debug it - but it's the right approach. perhaps add a select as in *select newID" at the end to get it into the result set.